# how to stop adding tabbed panel within a tabbed panel in Netbean IDE 6.8

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

how to stop adding tabbed panel within a tabbed panel in Netbean IDE 6.8.

i want to add a frame in a tabbed panel but whenever i do, it creates another tabbed panel frame in that main tab. what should i do?

plz help

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I right click on the tabbedPane in in Inspector window and choose 'add From Panel' / 'Swing Containers' / 'Panel' which creates a new tab (by adding a JPanel).

Comment: problem is resolved. when u drag any container be sure to place it on top of JtabPane then it will create container type tab else it will create a tab with in a tab of container type.